# ASP.NET + C# HttpContext.Current.Session is null (Inside WebService)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, null

this is how I initiate the session

```
 protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomSessionId"] = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
```

in my solution under a class library i am triyng to access it and getting null exception:

```
string sess = HttpContext.Current.Session["CustomSessionId"] ;
```

this is my config in web.config and app.config (in my library)

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
      <pages enableSessionState = "true" />
      <httpModules>
        <add type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" name="Session"/>
      </httpModules>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
```

(app.config)

Comment: At what stage of the execution of the HTTP request are you calling the method in your class library that tries to access the session?

Comment: it's hard to tell but I think it's not your Session that is null but the HttpContext.Current - and BTW: do you know that you try to convert a Guid to a string even if this works?

Comment: Actually it is inside a webservice that i did not mention (ill edit my post)

Comment: Just check the HttpContext.Current

Comment: I added the `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]`  and it is working, thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

According to your comments it seems that you are trying to access the session in a web service. Web services are stateless and that's how they should be. If you want to violate this rule and make them stateful you could enable sessions in a classic ASMX web service like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public void SomeMethod()
{
    ... invoke the method in your class library that uses Session
}
```

This being said, using `HttpContext.Current` in a class library is a very practice that should be avoided at all price.

Comment: Till I can tick the "V" for you, can you explain why it is not reccomended to do so? thanks

Comment: @putin, there are many reasons. For example HttpContext.Current is a static method which works only in a web context. This means that you will never be able to unit test your class library functions in isolation if they were relying on it. Another drawback is that you are actively coupling your class library to an ASP.NET environment and class libraries are meant to be reusable components. As far as the Session part is concerned, sessions are by default stored in memory of the web server. So for example if you run in a web farm, the session must be distributed ...

Comment: ... across all the nodes of this web farm or a client that had his session created on node1 won't find it on node2. Sessions make web applications stateful and more difficult to scale for that reason. Avoid them at all cost. There are so many other techniques in the HTTP world that would allow you to achieve stateless applications that you should benefit from.

Comment: can you point me for an example of technology the remove the need in session? thanks